# Linq to aggregate data across two dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq

I'm struggling with some linq to accomplish the following:

```
Dict1
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     1
5     2
6     2
7     2

Dict2

1     45
2     30
3     31
4     43
5     20
6     10
7     5
```

I want to sum the values in dictionary 2 based on the matching key in dictionary 1 and return the max or any default key with the results rolled up excluding values in dict 1 with a 0.

Eg:

```
New Dict
1    45
2    30
4    74
7    35
```

Comment: Your requirements aren't clear. Why are 3, 5 and 6 missing from the results?

Comment: I want to aggregate these results where the value in the original dictionary is not in 0 into a default key. Ergo, firstordefault, the max, etc.

Comment: @PMOrion still not clear, looks like expressing with words is not easy.

Comment: @PMOrion: Ah, I *think* I see what you mean, but it's not really clear. I'll try adding an answer...

Comment: If you are excluding values in the result where Dict1 values are 0 then why are values 1 and 2 in your results.  Looks like your results should contain keys 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7

Comment: I would post a code example but can't get the linq expression right to help clarify the intent.  :/  Example:  Key 3 and 4 have counts of 31 and 43 in dict 2.  I want to cross reference these keys against dict 1 and group where the value is > 0 into a single key and take the max of these keys or something to roll them up.

Comment: @PMOrion: Yes, but what about the 1 and 2 in your results? They don't match your description.

Comment: I only need to aggregate where the value is > 0.  The 0 values for the business are already considered aggregated.  I would love to refactor this from the client but am being forced currently to work with the existing dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get all of the pairs from the first dictionary where the value isn't zero, group them by the dictionary value, and then for each group it will represent one entry in the new dictionary.  The key of that entry is the max key from the group, the value is the sum of the values in the second dictionary for that key.

Then just add on the zero values to the end of that with `Concat` and throw it into a dictionary:

```
var newDict = dict1.Where(pair => pair.Value != 0)
        .GroupBy(pair => pair.Value)
        .Select(group => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(
            group.Max(pair => pair.Key),
            group.Where(pair => dict2.ContainsKey(pair.Key))
                .Sum(pair => dict2[pair.Key])))
        .Concat(dict1.Where(pair => pair.Value == 0))
        .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Comment: looks like this need 1 more `merging step` to include the original entries with `Value` being `Zero`?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're effectively grouping by the value in dictionary 1. I suspect you want *something* like:

```
var sums = from p1 in dict1
             where p1.Value != 0
             join p2 in dict2 on p1.Key equals p2.Key
             group p2 by p1.Value into g
             select new { Key = g.Max(p2 => p2.Key),
                          Sum = g.Sum(p2 => p2.Value) };
```

That gives a result of:

```
4 74
7 35
```

It doesn't include your {1, 45} or {2, 30} results though. I thought you wanted to ignore entries in the first dictionary with a value of 0?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add this answer as a reference. I don't understand why other answers start from `dict1`? while it's much more convenient and easy when we start from `dict2` like this:

```
var result = dict2.GroupBy(x => dict1[x.Key] == 0 ? dict1.Min(a=>a.Value) - x.Key :
                                                              dict1[x.Key])
                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Max(x=>x.Key), g => g.Sum(x => x.Value));
```

or if you don't care about `1-line LINQ solution`, just declare some variable holding the min value of `dict1` (this way of course has much better performance):

```
var min = dict1.Min(a=>a.Value);
var result = dict2.GroupBy(x => {
                     var d = dict1[x.Key];
                     return d == 0 ? min - Math.Abs(x.Key) : d;
                  }).ToDictionary(g => g.Max(x=>x.Key), g => g.Sum(x => x.Value));
```

**NOTE**: the code above can work in some limited conditions, it doesn't check `key existence` because it supposes 2 dicts have the same key collection (or at least all keys in `dict2` can be found in `dict1`. In the case there is an entry in `dict2` not matching any key in `dict1`, we need more rule to handle this case, such as keep the original entry in `dict2`...

Comment: 1) Why take a keyvalueapiar, grab the key from it, and then look up the value for that key?  Just grab the value from the pair.  You do this twice in the `GroupBy`. 2) Why calculate `min`?  If it's 0 then the program works, if it's not, it doesn't.  Just use `0` instead of `min`.  3) This doesn't support negative integers for keys, not sure if that's a real problem or not though. 4) You don't handle the case where one dictionary has values the other doesn't.

Comment: @Servy good point on the 4), for the 2) I don't agree, if group by `0`, we will have only 1 group of 2 entries (1 & 2), while the purpose is we need 2 groups, 1 for key 1 and the other for key 2. Well, you pointed out some very considerable problems. However I think it would be better with some modification, the `look-up` in a dictionary is not really bad if not wanting to say it's fast. I tested this code with the OP's sample input.

Comment: the purpose of calculating `min` or even `max` is to find a way to get different values for `groupby` if the entries (of dict1) have value of `0`

Comment: But you don't need to calculate the min, you can just use zero and have all negative group keys be the keys for the zero group, and all positive keys be the keys for the non-zero groups.  You just can't support negative keys in the second dictionary if you do that (which you can't support anyway, for different reasons).  All in all, you're just generally trying to be too clever.  It makes the code much harder to understand, much harder to debug, and has introduced several minor bugs into the code.  Just add the extra few lines of code to write it out as the requirements read instead.

Comment: @Servy if so, we can use `max` instead and the `min - x.Key` will be changed to `max + x.key`. The purpose is to create different `groupby` values for different `zero` entries in `dict1` and the values **should not** be any one of other `groupby` values (which are used for `non-zero` entries). As I said, this is posted as a reference. I think you should try modify it and feel how it's better this way.

Comment: Fundimentally, unless there is an int range that none of the key can be in then it can't work.  If you know there are no negative keys then just negate the number, if you *can't make that assertion then you need a more fundamental change to ensure that the object is always different if the dictionary value is zero.

Comment: @Servy thanks for clarification, I talked about the purpose of calculating `min` or `max`, maybe there is another better way.

Comment: Your problem isn't just keys with the value `0` being negative, and thus being positive after being negated.  If you have a negative key with a non-zero value then it can collide with a zero valued key that has the same magnitude for a key.  Your change doesn't really affect that.  Again, the fundamental problem is that you have a key that already spans the entire int range, and you're trying to apply a special meaning to some segment of it.  If you move those that were there before elsewhere, you can cause collisions.  It's better to just not fit it all into an int in the first place.

Comment: @Servy `a key that already spans the entire int range`, well it looks like too large dictionary :), OK looks like using `int` values as the `groupby` values could cause problem, if so we can use some `string` values instead, it may cost more but it should work, then we can use `Guid` to generate unique string easily, thank you for all comments, I didn't notice about the problems before although the idea is OK I think.

Comment: Any given dictionary doesn't need to actually have all 4.2 billion values; it only need two for there to be a conflict.  The point is that you, at compile time, can't know that there is a range of integers that will never be picked.  While one dictionary won't have all of the values, some dictionary somewhere can have any given value that you choose.